# Referencing session variables in PHP

Tags: php, session

Lets say I'm storing an array or object called `$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]`.

If I need to refer to it repeatedly throughout the script, which of the following is the "best practice"?

- Use `$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]` each time (i.e. `$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]["first_name"]`)?
- Copy the object into a new variable like `$logged_in = $_SESSION["logged_in_user"]`?
- Create a reference to the session variable like `$logged_in =& $_SESSION["logged_in_user"]`

I'm probably overthinking this, but my main concerns are script overhead and readability. I'm not sure if referring to a session variable repeatedly is slower than referring to an inline-declared variable. I also don't know if copying a session variable into a "regular" variable adds more overhead than is necessary. I do like the readability of `$logged_in["first_name"]` over `$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]["first_name"]`.

So is there a best practice here, or does it really not matter?

Comment: it really doesn't matter. Whatever makes sense to you. A reference does seem like a bit overkill though. Personally, id go with creating a new variable.

Comment: I've never seen a reference variable created for a `$_SESSION` variable, but this looks like micro optimization, and is really your preference.

Comment: I usually create a class that deals with users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not overthinking it.... thinking is good!

I personally use symfony 1.4 to code in, which solves problems like these, but you may choose to stay lean :-)

I'd think OO (object oriented). Create a user class. Then make calls like UserFactory::getCurrentUser() or User::getCurrentUser() which will return the currently logged in user object. Among the member variables of that class would be the user_id. However, you'll be able to add addition functionality and data to that class.

Remember, thinking in OO means using abstract terms that are very close to the problem domain. User, Car, Order, etc. You don't have to be specific and you don't have to include all available information in that class for it to be "complete", whatever that is. Only include the data that you need at the time (keep [yagni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) in mind). The classes are illusions of the concrete, real-world things. Just as 3D modelling is an illusion of a real world thing.

Hope that helps...

Comment: totally. that's precisely what I meant by a session wrapper class.

Answer (score 8):

`$_SESSION` is a special PHP superglobal array. So you technically can refer to it whenever you want by just using it:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in_user']
```

However, it's special as well because it can change. The following example makes this visible:

```
$alias =& $_SESSION;
session_start();
$alias['foo'] = 'bar';
```

This code won't set `$_SESSION['foo']`. The `$alias` is pointing to a previous `$_SESSION`, `session_start()` has created a new session.

If you know the caveats like these you can naturally create your own `$_SESSION` abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

You're not over-thinking it in my opinion.

But unless you have some session wrapper/manager class, then I would just use:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in_user']
```

Either way it's not a huge deal.  Use whatever works for *you*.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to manage your session:

```
class MySession {

  public static &get( $key ){

    if( !array_key_exists( $key, $_SESSION ){
      return null;
    } 

    return $_SESSION[$key];

  }

}
```

That way you don't have to worry about how to retrieve values, you're not duplicating any data:

```
$first_name = MySession::get( 'first_name' );
```

Note: this solution deals with accessing the session and not with your specific implementation :)

Comment: I like this. I still have a hard time thinking in terms of static classes (I understand the concept, but they never jump to mind as a solution). One question, in this case, wouldn't I still have to call `$first_name = MySession::get("logged_in_user['first_name']")`?

Comment: You can use it directly too, it doesn't really matter. You need to do what makes the most sense for each specific case. As for the specific example you're referencing, you'd have to get the "logged_in_user" array first and then retrieve the first_name from it.. As I said, this was only a suggestion on how to deal with the session. Your specific implementation calls for a combination of this plus what Homer6 said.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]["first_name"]
```

Stay simple; & don't add over heads for making new rooms for the same variables.